# How can I reference a .NET Standard 2.0 class libary from a UWP app?

Tags: uwp, .net-standard-2.0

So according to Microsoft in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/) article:

> "With the release of .NET Standard 2.0, we’re now officially
>   deprecating PCLs and you should move your projects to .NET Standard"

Great. I would love to. Except I cannot reference a .NET Standard 2.0 class library from my Universal Windows app. How can this be?

Does Microsoft really expect that if I were to start a new multi-platform solution (involving an UWP client app) today, that shared code would have to be in obsolete PCL form? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read it again carefully, you will see this

> Upcoming version of UWP (expected to ship later this year)

So no you cannot at the moment as it's yet to be supported.

Update: this post just came out so basically you can now target 2.0 with the latest Visual Studio 2017 15.4.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/25/uwp-net-standard-2-0-preview/

Comment: I was hoping there was some magical workaround, but I guess not. Thank you.